# I have a problem with printing a Multi - Line string

Tags: python, string, printing

I am trying to make a hangman game and I have this multi - line string:

```
stage10 = """|--------- 
|/       | 
|       /-\
|        O 
|       /|\
|        | 
|       / \
|          
|__________"""
```

But when I print it:

```
print(stage10)
```

I get:

```
|--------- 
|/       | 
|       /-|        O 
|       /||        | 
|       / |          
|__________
```

Can someone point out my mistake? (if any) or is there something I need to add?
Help aprreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape backslash chars if you want to have a pretty print of them. So here your solution :

```py
stage10 = """|--------- 
|/       | 
|       /-\\
|        O 
|       /|\\
|        | 
|       / \\
|          
|__________"""

print(stage10)
```

Output:

```
|--------- 
|/       | 
|       /-\
|        O 
|       /|\
|        | 
|       / \
|          
|__________
```

Answer (score 1):

The backward slash is a special character that gets removed.
Use double `\\` instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

string should accommodate \ as an escape character. Use `\\` instead of `\`

```
stage10 = """|--------- 
|/       | 
|       /-\\
|        O 
|       /|\\
|        | 
|       / \\
|          
|__________"""
```